# Can "Bump Sequence" potentially lock an account?

Tags: sequence-number

"Bump Sequence" allows you to set the sequence number of the account to any number between 0 to INT64_MAX (9223372036854775807)

I had a suspicion that I just verified, I created an account on the testnet, and bumped it's sequence to INT64_MAX. Now I cannot perform any more transactions with this account since its sequence number is too high (INT64_MAX + 1)

Am I missing something, or is it really possible to lock an account from doing anything using this operation?

Its a low threshold operation, so multisig account would need to set their "low threshold" to a high number to avoid it, which will be weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still possible to issue operations that affect that account, as the sequence number is consumed by the account issuing the transaction. You could use a second account to merge the max-id account.